# python stack method for reverse string code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use the stack method to get reverse string in this revers question.
"Write a function revstring(mystr) that uses a stack to reverse the characters in a string."
This is my code.

```
from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack
def revstring(mystr):

    myStack = Stack()   //this is how i have myStack

    for ch in mystr:   //looping through characters in my string
        myStack.push(ch)   //push the characters to form a stack

        revstr = ''  //form an empty reverse string
        while not myStack.isEmpty():

            revstr = revstr + myStack.pop()  //adding my characters to the empty reverse string in reverse order
            return revstr

print revstring("martin")
```

**the output seems to print out only the first letter of mystr that is "m"**
why this??

Comment: Because your `return` statement is part of your `while` block. Which is itself part of your `for` block. In other words, your indentation needs work.

Comment: Can you at least post valid Python code? Python uses `#` for comments, not `//`.

Comment: You need to *unindent* code that is not part of the loop anymore. Your `while` loop is executed for each iteration of the `for` loop. Your `return` ends both the `while` and the `for` loop, because it is part of both.

Comment: Finally got it!! thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

Here's 3 solutions to the same problem, just pick one:

**1ST SOLUTION**

Fixing your solution, you almost got it, you just need to indent properly
your blocks like this:

```
from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack


def revstring(mystr):

    myStack = Stack() # this is how i have myStack

    for ch in mystr: # looping through characters in my string
        myStack.push(ch) # push the characters to form a stack

    revstr = '' # form an empty reverse string
    while not myStack.isEmpty():
        # adding my characters to the empty reverse string in reverse order
        revstr = revstr + myStack.pop()

    return revstr

print revstring("martin")
```

**2ND SOLUTION**

This one is structurally the same than yours but instead of using a custom stack, it's just using the builtin python list

```
def revstring(mystr):

    myStack = [] # this is how i have myStack

    for ch in mystr:
        myStack.append(ch) # push the characters to form a stack

    revstr = '' # form an empty reverse string
    while len(myStack):
        # adding my characters to the empty reverse string in reverse order
        revstr = revstr + myStack.pop()

    return revstr

print revstring("martin")
```

**3RD SOLUTION**

To reverse strings, just use this pythonic way :)

```
print "martin"[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

- the `while` should not be in the `for`
- the `return` should be outside, not in the `while`

**code:**

```
from pythonds.basic.stack import Stack

def revstring(mystr):

    myStack = Stack()      # this is how i have myStack

    for ch in mystr:       # looping through characters in my string
        myStack.push(ch)   # push the characters to form a stack

    revstr = ''            # form an empty reverse string
    while not myStack.isEmpty():
        # adding my characters to the empty reverse string in reverse order
        revstr = revstr + myStack.pop()

    return revstr


print revstring("martin")
```